# JSON: Better to use one object (key/val pairs), or two objects to separate data from model?

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures, data-modeling

I haven't implemented too much JSON, so I'm curious if there is an advised approach to handling data.  I'm guessing that there are two main approaches (perhaps they are invalid JSON), but I'd like see if there is any additional pluses/minuses, or a better approach?

---

**Approach 1**: Combination of Key/Value Pairs

```
var all_in_one = { "person"  : [{
                                  "firstName" : "John",
                                  "lastName"  : "Smith",
                                  "phone"     : [{ 
                                                   "areaCode"  : "800", 
                                                   "number"    : "222-3333" 
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                   "areaCode"  : "800",
                                                   "number"    : "222-3334",
                                                   "extension" : "1111"
                                                 }]
                                },
                                {
                                  "firstName" : "John",
                                  "lastName"  : "Rolfe"
                                },
                                {...}],
                   "other"    : [{...}]
                 };
```

Benefits:

- Keys are close to values (more visual and clearer code when looping and pulling the values)
- Values/Keys are not required (fluid model/structure)

Problems:

- More overhead for multiple records (repetition of keys)

---

**Approach 2**: Separation of Keys from Values

```
var json = { "model" : { "person" : ["firstName","lastName",["areaCode","number","extension"]],
                         "other"  : [...]
                       },
             "data"  : { "person" : [["John","Smith",[["800","222-3333",undefined],
                                                      ["800","222-3334","1111"]]],
                                     ["John","Rolfe",[[undefined,undefined,undefined]],
                                     [...]
                                    ],
                         "other"  : [...]
                       }
            };
```

Benefits:

- Less overhead (keys defined once)
- Static model/structure which can be changed in one place

Problems:

- Static model/structure can be more problematic if expected to change
- Code may be more confusing when extracting data

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen anyone use approach 2.  It doesn't separate the "data from the model"; that doesn't make sense, anyway, since the data **is** the model.  All you've done is make it really hard to tell what any of the data *is*.

I suppose now you can rename a field in one place, but that has got to be one of the least common types of schema changes.  Adding a field, moving a field, removing a field, swapping two fields, making a field optional, etc. will all be an unverifiable nightmare.

(And as for the overhead, gzip will take care of it on the wire, and your JSON decoder and/or language are hopefully smart enough to reuse the same string object for each repeated key.)

Comment: I may have been incorrect when I came up with these examples.  But I was calling it a model in the sense that it's the data definition that is used when pulling the data.  So you would look through that, to get the object type (string/array) and use the structure to pull out the data.

Comment: Regarding the JSON decoder.  When I had been doing SOAP requests (years ago), it had been suggested that common use of JSON (still newish) would eventually be a better alternative as it had less repetition.  Could you point to what you mean by the JSON decoder as it seems that is what I'm trying to build, when something may already exist; otherwise I'm guessing you mean to take a string JSON string and parse it into a hash or struct-like object.

Comment: a JSON decoder is just something that turns a JSON string into a native data structure, yes.

Comment: @vol7ron from what I understand, you mean schema rather than model (which is the terminology used in Eevee's answer).

Comment: @Christophe: for all practical purposes, I think in a MVC framework that they would be considered one in the same.  As I mentioned in my comment, I'd intend to use the schema/model as a structure (think looping structure) of what to expect from the passed data.  Such that the data would need to be in that structure to validate and be turned into information properly.  --- *Thinking on it further, I'm curious if I should pass the other metadata too (eg dataType, relationships)*

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen your approach 2 in the form of an object, but it looks very similar to datatables, where the first array contains the column names and the others contain the data.

I see two main issues with the second approach:

- It is more rigid (for example it won't be easy to add another phone property)
- it's not convenient with sparse data as you end up with a lot of "undefined"

The clear benefit is that the data size is much smaller, as property names don't need to be repeated.

Bottom line: I use the second approach if the data would fit nicely in a table (only a few empty cells) and the dataset is large.

[Edit] As for your question "I'm curious if I should pass the other metadata too", this is definitely an added benefit of the second approach. As I already mentioned in the comments, Google Visualization is a good example. I also work with Microsoft SharePoint 2013 which does exactly that. Here is an example from SharePoint:

```
{"Name": "Editor",
"FieldType": "User",
"RealFieldName": "Editor",
"DisplayName": "Modified By",
...
"AllowGridEditing": "FALSE"}
```

Comment: I placed `undefined`s there, but in reality they'd probably be null bytes or blanks.  I'm looking for a way to keep it in clear text, but with reduced repetition (file size) w/o relying on compression (gzip) in case it is not enabled.

Comment: The issue is that null or blank might have a different meaning, so you really want to say undefined when it is. Right (and as I said in my answer), the second approach is better for dense data and when size is a concern. For example this is used in charting tools like Google visualization.